# How to allow non mocked endpoints when using responses library

Tags: python, python-requests, python-responses

In Python it's really common to use `requests` [library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to make your HTTP requests.

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('http://google.com')
print(f"Code: {r.status_code}\nText head: {r.text[:100]}")

>>> Code: 200
>>> Text head: <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="es"><head><meta content
```

Then, it's also really common to mock HTTP requests using `responses` [library](https://github.com/getsentry/responses).

```py
import requests
import responses

@responses.activate
def my_request():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://google.com', body="Hi! Mocked :)")
    r = requests.get('http://google.com')
    return r

r = my_request()
print(f"Code: {r.status_code}\nText head: {r.text[:100]}")

>>> Code: 200
>>> Text head: Hi! Mocked :)
```

However, I've an use case in which I need an endpoint to be mocked, and another one to be actually used.

E.g. Actually access the `'http://google.com'` endpoint to run the function, then mock other data from another endpoint and test my function.

However, in this situation I found that the endpoint that I would actually want to visit fails just because is not available within `responses` current mocked endpoints.

```py
import requests
import responses

@responses.activate
def my_request():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://google.com', body="Hi! Mocked :)")
    # To be mocked
    r1 = requests.get('http://google.com')
    # To actually access
    r2 = requests.get('http://bing.com')
    return r1, r2

r1, r2 = my_request()
print(f"Code r1: {r1.status_code}\nCode r2: {r2.status_code}")
```

Produces as output:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in wrapper
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in my_request
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/responses/__init__.py", line 765, in unbound_on_send
    return self._on_request(adapter, request, *a, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/responses/__init__.py", line 745, in _on_request
    raise response
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by Responses - the call doesn't match any registered mock.

Request:
- GET http://bing.com/

Available matches:
- GET http://google.com/ URL does not match
```

How can I make `responses` to allow reaching some actual non-mocked endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`responses` [library has a mechanism](https://github.com/getsentry/responses#passing-through-real-requests) to allow this using the `add_passthru` function. Its behaviour is similar to the `add` function but it just needs the `endpoint` and no further data.

It's also important to notice that if the endpoint resolves to a different URL, it won't work. For example, adding it to the example:

```py
import requests
import responses

@responses.activate
def my_request():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://google.com', body="Hi! Mocked :)")
    responses.add_passthru('http://bing.com')
    # To be mocked
    r1 = requests.get('http://google.com')
    # To actually access
    r2 = requests.get('http://bing.com')
    return r1, r2

r1, r2 = my_request()
print(f"Code r1: {r1.status_code}\nCode r2: {r2.status_code}")
```

Will produce an error because `r2` request will try to connect to `http://www.bing.com`, and the endpoint was defined **without** the `www`: `http://bing.com`

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in wrapper
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in my_request
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 677, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 677, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 237, in resolve_redirects
    resp = self.send(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/responses/__init__.py", line 765, in unbound_on_send
    return self._on_request(adapter, request, *a, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/responses/__init__.py", line 745, in _on_request
    raise response
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by Responses - the call doesn't match any registered mock.

Request:
- GET http://www.bing.com/
```

Modifying the `passthru` defined endpoint will solve this issue:

```py
    # responses.add_passthru('http://bing.com')
    responses.add_passthru('http://www.bing.com')
```

Comment: Over 500 people viewed this question and I'm the first person ever to upvote it? Strange...